# How to explain run 5 (x) g0 g1 in The Reasoned Schemer

Tags: scheme, reasoned-schemer

I don't understand how the run n (x) g0 g1 ... to run through listo

the listo is defined like this

```lisp
(define listo
  (lambda (l)
    (conde
      [(nullo l) #s)]
      [(pairo l)
       (fresh (d)
         (cdro l d)
         (listo d))]
      [else #u])))
```

The Reasoned Schemer on page 29 in segment 14 says the code

```lisp
(run 5 (x)
  (listo (a b c . x)))
```

produces the result

```lisp
(()
 (_.0)
 (_.0 _.1)
 (_.0 _.1 _.2)
 (_.0 _.1 _.2 _.3))
```

Would you explain how does this happened ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's explained in a lot of detail in the preceding 28 pages. Have you reviewed those? (The book looks simple, but you can't rush through it. I often go "what?" and need to back up a bit.)

Answer (score 3):

The query is

```
(run 5 (x)
  (listo `(a b c . ,x)))
```

I've added quasiquote `` ` `` and unquote `,`, the book uses bold and non-bold text for that:

```
(run5 (x)
  (listo (a b c . x)))
```

anyway the way `listo` works is it tries to check `` (nullo `(a b c . ,x)) `` and this fails, so it tries to check `` (pairo `(a b c . ,x)) `` and this succeeds. So it follows that branch of the `conde` and runs

```
(fresh (d)
     (cdro `(a b c . ,x) d)
     (listo              d))
```

the `cdro` produces `` d = `(b c . ,x) `` so we have

```
(fresh (d)
     ; (cdro `(a b c . ,x) `(b c . ,x))  ;; disappears, has been solved
     (listo                `(b c . ,x)))
```

So now this whole process repeats for `` (listo `(b c . ,x)) `` and then `` (listo `(c . ,x)) `` and then `(listo x)`

That's also the only possible branch that can be taken, so `` (listo `(a b c . ,x)) `` is logically equivalent to `(listo x)`. Both queries will produce the same results.